# insert into table as data return from stored procedure

Tags: mysql

i want to store data returned from stored procedure to a table.
i have tried this.

```
insert into table1 call sp_test();
```

but it fails.

how do i do this ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [MySQL How to INSERT INTO \[temp table\] FROM \[Stored Procedure\]](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/687102/mysql-how-to-insert-into-temp-table-from-stored-procedure)

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
call sp_test(@var)    
insert into table1 (select @var);
```

And in procedure there shoud be out variable in arguments

Comment: This is the beginning of the right answer: you can't redirect or use the 'output' of the stored procedures. The answer would be better completed with how the inside of the stored procedure should look like.

Answer (score 0):

If it returns data, it is a [stored function, not a stored procedure](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/create-procedure.html). In that case you don't use `CALL` but simply use it in a [`INSERT … SELECT`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/insert-select.html) statement, like this:

```
INSERT INTO table1 SELECT sp_test()
```

Comment: Then it has to have parameters to return anything through them, and your example didn't indicate any. WIthout those, the result of your queries inside the SP will be lost once the procedure returns.

Answer (score -1):

for `function` use `select`

```
insert into table1 select sp_test();
```

[how to insert into...stored-procedure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/687102/mysql-how-to-insert-into-temp-table-from-stored-procedure)

Comment: my sp return more than one row while function return only one value