# Inserting values in temporary table in mysql Procedure

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, prepared-statement, procedure

I have a procedure like below

```
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS mp_search_result;
CREATE PROCEDURE mp_search_result()                                                   
BEGIN
      CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE temp_projids(projid int);

       SET @strSearchSQL = 'SELECT DISTINCT project_id
                             FROM tblProjects'; 

      PREPARE stmt FROM @strSearchSQL;
      INSERT INTO temp_projids(projid) values ();
      EXECUTE stmt;
      DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;       

END;
```

Now I want to insert the project ids returned by the above query into a temporary table.

I am confused with where to write the insert query before execution.

Please note that my requirement is different from query which I posted above.

I am using many if conditions and concatenation for forming `@strSearchSQL`.

I removed those to prevent the complexity in code.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS mp_search_result;
CREATE PROCEDURE mp_search_result()                                                   
BEGIN
      CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE temp_projids(projid int);

       SET @strSearchSQL = 'INSERT INTO temp_projids(projid)  SELECT DISTINCT project_id
                             FROM tblProjects'; 

      PREPARE stmt FROM @strSearchSQL;
      EXECUTE stmt;
      DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;       

END;
```

Comment: #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 3