# PHPmyadmin error when trying to insert stored procedure results to table

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database, phpmyadmin

I am trying to store table results of two stored procedures to a single table in phpmyadmin routine window which gives me mariadb syntax error. Calling the stored procedures separately gives me the results.

Stored procedure code

```
BEGIN
CREATE TABLE temp(Name VARCHAR(200), Value1 varchar(100), Value2 varchar(100))
INSERT INTO temp CALL stored_procedure1();
INSERT INTO temp CALL stored_procedure2();
END
```

This code gives me the following syntax error

The following query has failed:

```
"CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `get_data`() NOT DETERMINISTIC NO SQL SQL SECURITY DEFINER BEGIN CREATE TABLE temp(Name VARCHAR(200), Value1 varchar(100), Value2 varchar(100)) INSERT INTO temp CALL stored_procedure1(); INSERT INTO temp CALL stored_procedure2(); END"
```

MySQL said: #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'INSERT INTO temp CALL stored_procedure1();

I tried changing syntax of TABLE temp to TABLE #temp and adding ; at the end of create table statement which did not resolve it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MySQL How to INSERT INTO \[temp table\] FROM \[Stored Procedure\]](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/687102/mysql-how-to-insert-into-temp-table-from-stored-procedure)

Answer (score 0):

First, you should change default delimiter which is `;` to something like `//`

Also, i assume you forgot to put `CREATE PROCEDURE Something()` statement here.

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE PROCEDURE Something()
BEGIN
CREATE TABLE temp(Name VARCHAR(200), Value1 varchar(100), Value2 varchar(100));
INSERT INTO temp CALL stored_procedure1();
INSERT INTO temp CALL stored_procedure2();
END//
DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I tried using delimiters which gives me the following syntax error message      
MySQL said: #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '// CREATE PROCEDURE get_data()

Comment: I tried modifying the code as per your latest reply, now it gives me the following error MySQL said: #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '// CREATE PROCEDURE get_data() BEGIN CREATE TABLE temp(Name VARCHAR(200), V' at line 3

Comment: FYI I am working on PHPmyadmin edit routine window to add or edit the SP