# Call Stored Procedure While Inserting

Tags: mysql

I am trying to insert values from one table to another one using the following insert sql query

```
INSERT INTO [dbo].[table2] 
SELECT Exec [StoredProcedure],
       [Column1]
      ,[Column2]
FROM [dbo].[table1]
```

[table2] has the following columns:

1. RecNo,    <-- INT
2. Column1,   <--VARCHAR(50)
3. Column2    <--VARCHAR(50)

[StoredProcedure] main purpose is that every time a new row to be inserted in table2 it selects the maximum value from RecNo from table2 and adds 1 to that number to create the next number (sequential). 
Here is the script for the stored procedure .

```
GO
ALTER  PROCEDURE [dbo].[UpdateRcnoNumbers]
@MaxRcno INT OUTPUT
AS
BEGIN 
 SELECT  @MaxRcno=MAX(Recno) FROM [table2]
 SELECT @MaxRcno=@MaxRcno+1
 RETURN @MaxRcno
END
```

But I am getting an error and I am not able to call the stored procedure ? Any suggestion please .

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1):

You should write a function for this purpose , read here

> The problem is, Stored Procedures don't really return output directly. They can execute select statements inside the script, but have no return value.
>   MySQL calls stored procedures via CALL StoredProcedureName(); And you cannot direct that output to anything, as they don't return anything (unlike a function).

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/687102/mysql-how-to-insert-into-temp-table-from-stored-procedure)

[MySQL Call Command](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/call.html)