# MySQL stored procedure call in EXISTS statement

Tags: mysql, procedure, exists

I have a stored procedure that returns some data from a table. I want to use that data in another query by calling the stored procedure. this is what I've tried so far:

```
SELECT T.ID, T.USER_ID, T.CONTENT, T.POSTAGE
    FROM post as T
    WHERE T.USER_ID  (CALL MyFollowers());
```

I get a syntax error on `CALL`. so I guessed I cant use return value of a stored procedure on `IN` or `EXISTS`keyword. is there any other way to do this?

Comment: I you can show what `MyFollowers` does then other answers may  be possible. Did you create the procedure to solve some specific problem? Which MySQL version?

Answer (score 0):

after some searching I found this:

> The problem is, Stored Procedures don't really return output directly. They can execute select statements inside the script but have no return value. MySQL calls stored procedures via CALL StoredProcedureName(); And you cannot direct that output to anything, as they don't return anything (unlike a function). MySQL Call Command

the original post is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/687102/mysql-how-to-insert-into-temp-table-from-stored-procedure/692146)